# Getting unique indices of minimum values in multiple lists

Tags: python, list

I am having some trouble getting my head around this problem.

Let's say I have n lists each containing n elements.
For each list, I need to find the index of the minimum value and store them in a new list. This is easy enough.

The problem is, two or more values in my index list might be equal. I need a list with unique values. If two (or more) values are equal, I want to prioritize the index value which came from the smalles minimum value.

Example:

```
myLists = []
myLists.append([113.6, 12262.6, 21466.7, 141419.9])      # list 1
myLists.append([122284.8, 111161.8, 106581.1, 141419.9]) # list 2
myLists.append([25427.9, 13694.0, 5148.9, 141419.9])     # list 3
myLists.append([21354.9, 10599.2, 0.1, 141419.9])        # list 4
```

This would give me the index list [0,2,2,2]. Based on the 2nd value in lists 2, 3 and 4, I see that the smallest is in list 4, so my index list should look like [0,?,?,2].

Going further, I need to fill in the question marks with the values 1 and 3, but which goes where? From inspection, I see that since 13694.0 (index 1 from list 3) is smaller than 111161.8 (index 1 from list 2) and the third index values in each list are equal, I should choose index 1 from list 3.

This means my new index list is [0,?,1,2]. With only one question mark left, I fill this with 3. This gives [0,3,1,2].

The lists will mostly be small, so running time is not really an issues here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I merged all the lists in form of 3 member tuples *(value, index of list in myLists, index of value in list)* and sorted it by value. Time complexity of my code is *nlog(n)*.

```
myLists = []
myLists.append([113.6, 12262.6, 21466.7, 141419.9])  # list 1
myLists.append([122284.8, 111161.8, 106581.1, 141419.9])  # list 2
myLists.append([25427.9, 13694.0, 5148.9, 141419.9])  # list 3
myLists.append([21354.9, 10599.2, 0.1, 141419.9])  # list 4

merged_list = list()

for index1, ls in enumerate(myLists):
    for index2, x in enumerate(ls):
        merged_list.append((x, index1, index2))

merged_list.sort()

st = set()  #to store already added indices

res = [-1 for i in range(len(myLists))]

for x, y, z in merged_list:
    if res[y] != -1 or z in st:
        continue
    res[y] = z
    st.add(z)

print(res)
```

Output -

```
[0, 3, 1, 2]
```